# How to count files between two time stamps

Tags: timestamps

I need to count number of files processed during some period. For e.g the number of files processed between 9am to 10am. I tried below but it is not working.

```
wc -l | -mtime JAN 17 10:00 +mtime JAN 17 10:05
```

Comment: What is that supposed to be? Have you ever worked with the shell?

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -type f -newermt "today 10:00" -not -newermt "today 17:00" -printf . | 
  wc -c
```

Comment: Default output (i.e. `-print`) combined with `wc -l` might be more useful, since that makes sense even without the `wc` counter (i.e. can be then reused).

Comment: @peterph But fails with paths which contain `\n`.

Comment: that's true (though not very common).